# Set dynamic height constraint on collectionviewcell which is in uitableviewcell based on image height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, uicollectionview

I am trying to add custom height constraint to collection view cell which is present in uitableview cell. The height of constraint is dependent on image which needs to be fetched from url(Using sdwebimage to fetch image in collectionviewcell). Trying to to update constraint in sizeforitem in collectionviewcell. The problem i am facing because of this is that initially fixed height is getting set as per storyboard constraint and as soon as i am scrolling the height constraint is getting updated which is creating problems.

Need to know following
1)Need to know a proper way to implement this thing
2)Where and how should i update constraint so that the tableviewcell as well as collectionviewcell will be set to exact height as of image
3)Exactly where should i download images from sdwebimage

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/brWvy.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDh8I.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set height for collection view cell in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

I think this will be helpful to you.

This function will be called every time once user start to swipe Up/Down or Left/Right in the case of the Horizontal collection view.

Comment: Can you please guide more on where should i call sdwebimage download. Cause tried to use will display cell collectionview method but still the height is not changing properly. Also the call back of sdwebimage comes later so until the height is set the image goes out of view.

Comment: You can call sdwebimage download in cellForIndexPath method, just get the height of image in willDisplay cell method.